# Why does Ambari cluster setup fails at zookeeper installation with a error in symlink?

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm trying to install HortanWorks Ambari-Server in a local setup and I'm running into a problem with the Kafka client installation. Following error pops up when I try to setup the cluster.

```
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 
'ambari-python-wrap /usr/bin/hdp-select set zookeeper-client 2.6.3.0-235' 
returned 1. symlink target /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client for zookeeper 
already exists and it is not a symlink.
```

How to correct this issue? I've looked into the HDP problem discussion as well [[1](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/148134/zookeeper-server-2630-235-returned-1.html)] but the answers that are given there seems to not work for me. Can someone please elaborate what needs to be done to correct this issue ?

HDP discussion [[1](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/148134/zookeeper-server-2630-235-returned-1.html)]

Answer (score 0):

Error is self explanatory and it indicates directory or file `/usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client` already exist. Hence to resolve issue you need to delete directory or file `/usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client` and then create correct soft link.

```
mv /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client_back
ln -s /usr/hdp/2.6.3.0-235/zookeeper /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client
```